# php, extract data from a non-standard xml document

Tags: php, xml

I have some kind xml content I need to extract the information and store it into database

```
<xml file="136000000-136100000">
<Id>136000000</Id>
<Name>Sem  Serxy</Na me>
<Email>ssunsdadi2sk@ya.ru</Email>
<DateRegistration>10/13/2010 1:49:30 AM</DateRegistration>
</xml>
<xml file="136000000-136100000">
<Id>136000001</Id>
<Name>God Deckor</Name>
<Email>deckor22s2001@yahoo.com</Email>
```

If I try simple xml load is not working as the document doesn't seem to be valid xml.
  I can use regex to extract the info with preg_match_all but I feel this is not the right way as the data is already well structured. Any other method ?

Comment: Just to note, if it isn't valid, it isn't actually XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<root>' + $record->rows['ColumnName'] + '</root>');
$xmlelmId = $xml->xpath('/root/Id');
echo $xmlelmId[0];
```

Comment: can you also let me know what $record is ?

Comment: Sorry. I'm paste my framework code. It should be: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $xml = simplexml_load_string('<root>' + $row['XmlDataColumnName'] + '</root>'); $xmlelmId = $xml->xpath('/root/Id'); echo $xmlelmId[0]; }

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in a root-element. It looks otherwise valid to me.

Eg. something like this:

```
$xmlData = '<root>' . $xmlData . '</root>';
```

Where `$xmlData` is a string containing the data you have.

This way you should be able to load it using SimpleXML or other XML-libraries in PHP.

Comment: it still says 
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: 136000000-136100000.xml:7: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: <xml file="136000000-136100000"> in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 3

Comment: Adding to what @JaniHartikainen mentioned, maybe also add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` to the beginning, then wrap it in a parent node, then parse. (this is assuming it does at least follow the `<xml file="xxx">...</xml>` pattern and doesn't leave out closing tags (like your snippet does) and doesn't _actually_ have a `</Na me>` tag in it)

Comment: well actually the code snipped is extracted in the exactly same form from the xml document so it has </Name>  etc